# QProcess : Reset working directory during runtime

Tags: c++, qt, directory, reset, qprocess

I'm using the `QProcess` class from Qt to communicate between a Qt-GUI Application and program written in C. When I start the GUI I set the working directory of `QProcess`.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to **reset the chosen working directory of `QProcess` during runtime**. I did not find any function in the QT documentation.

The User should enter some file-paths into the GUI which passes them to the C Program (Crypto program). Besides the file paths entered in the GUI the C Program loads some files on his own from the current working Directory.

E.g.  The User wants to verify a File which is stored together with a Signature at a Directory A. The public Key from the Signer is in Directory B. 
The User can enter the path to the public Key in the GUI (works)
The User can enter the path to a new working Directory in the GUI (**does not work**)

I have a QPushButton "set new working Directory" which emits the SIGNAL clicked to a SLOT where I call :

```
// _dataWDict->text() gets the Text Input from a QLineEdit Widget
// from the _userWidget (= "GUI")

QString pathWDict = _userWidget->_dataWDict->text();
_process->setWorkingDirectory(pathWDict);

// displays me the output in the GUI
_userWidget->_log->append(_process->workingDirectory());
```

Calling `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory` purports to be diffrent but I still can only access the Files in the working Directory from the start. From the Qt-Docs : " `QProcess` will start the process in this directory"

Comment: Can you please explain what problem you are trying to solve? I don't mean the solution you want help with (changing directory) but the original problem that makes you want to "reset" the working directory? Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `reset the chosen working directory of QProcess during runtime.` You can do that from the executable that runs in the QProcess however I do not believe it is possible from the executable that started the QProcess however you can use some form of IPC to signal the program that runs in the QProcess to change its folder.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on platform you can use [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) or [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Or why not [`QProcess::setWorkingDirectory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory)?

Comment: Maybe also `QDir::setCurrent`

Comment: using `QProcess::workingDirectory() ` after calling `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory` purports to be diffrent but I still can only access the Files in the working Directory from the start.  

From the Qt-Docs : " `QProcess`  will **start** the process in this directory"